# How to get a char* from a PyObject which points to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

How can I get a **char*** from a **PyObject** which points to a string. For example, this is the python script,

```
Test.Connect("272.22.20.65", 1234)
```

and this is the C++ code,

```
static PyObject* Connect(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject* pIP;
    PyObject* pPort;

    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "Connect", 2, 2, &pIP, &pPort)) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    const char* zIP = GetAsString(pIP);
    long iPort      = PyLong_AsLong(pPort);
```

I want to get that IP address as a char* (GetAsString is a dummy function :D ). Please note that I'm using Python 3.1.

P.S.
I don't think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570781/python-c-api-and-unicode-strings) question got the correct answer ,
 since there is no **PyStringObject** or **PyString_AsString** in Python 3. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Sven Marnach. it is str. But there is no way of getting char* from PyUnicode_*. Am I wrong ?

Comment: lol...where is Sven Marnach ? When I replied you, your comment was missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you [encode it](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_AsUTF8String), then you [retrieve it](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/bytes.html#PyBytes_AsString). Don't forget to decref the temporary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not working. PyBytes_AsString is returing a NULL. (in a simplify way this is how I used it, PyBytes_AsString(PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(pObject)) )

Comment: @Sven Marnach. Thanks for the point. I'm confused with python3, with python2x it is straightforward, isn't it.

Comment: Calling the two functions together like that will result in a memory leak.

Comment: I simplified it for commenting, it is like this. 
PyObject* pStrObj = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(pObject);
char* zStr  = PyBytes_AsString(pStrObj);
char* zStrDup = strdup(zStr);
Py_DECREF(pStrObj);

Hope I did it in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my portable recipe for it, which makes use the default encoding, where that is applicable. It assumes you start with a `PyObject*`, named `o`. If you still have your input tuple from the function call, you can skip the first 2 lines.

```
PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(O)", o);
/* Py_DECREF(o); if o is not borrowed */
if (!args) return 0;
const char* s = 0;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &s)) {
  Py_DECREF(args);
  return 0;
}

/* s now points to a const char* - use it, delete args when done */

Py_DECREF(args);
```

PS: I have not tested it, but it should work with older versions of Python as well. There is nothing on it which is version specific.