# Clean Way to Convert Python 3 Unicode to std::string

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I wrap a lot of C++ using the Python 2 API (I can't use things like swig or boost.python for various technical reasons). When I have to pass a string (usually a path, always ASCII) into C/C++, I use something like this:

```
std::string file_name = PyString_AsString(py_file_name); 
if (PyErr_Occurred()) return NULL;
```

Now I'm considering updating to Python 3, where `PyString_*` methods don't exist. I found [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896196/915501) that says I should do something like this:

```
PyObject* bytes = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(py_file_name);
std::string file_name = PyBytes_AsString(bytes); 
if (PyErr_Occurred()) return NULL; 
Py_DECREF(bytes);
```

However this is twice as many lines and seems a bit ugly (not to mention that it could introduce a memory leak if I forget the last line).

The other option is to redefine the python functions to operate on `bytes` objects, and to call them like this

```
def some_function(path_name):
    _some_function(path_name.encode('utf8'))
```

This isn't terrible, but it does require a python-side wrapper for each function.

Is there some cleaner way to deal with this?

Comment: Why not `std::wstring`?

Comment: Hmm, why would I use a `std::wstring`? I'm working exclusively with Linux, so as I understand it I probably don't need a `wstring` for anything.

Comment: Why not just wrap it in your own native function that converts the `PyObject` to `std::string`? `std::string convertPyString(PyObject* pyString);`

Comment: wrapping in a function is certainly better than using 4 lines each time I make the conversion, but I do this in several modules. If I use my own function I have to decide between linking them to a shared library (which adds a dependency) and copying the function into each module (which adds duplicate code). If there's some cleaner way to do this within the Python API that's preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the solution exists in python 3.3, with [`char* PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject* unicode)`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_AsUTF8). This should be exactly the same behavior as the `PyString_AsString()` function from python 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you know (and of course, you could check with an assert or similar) that it's all ASCII, then you could simply create it like this:

```
std::string py_string_to_std_string(PyUnicode_string py_file_name)
{
    len = length of py_file_name;     // Not sure how you write that in python. 
    std::string str(len); 
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        str += py_file_name[i]; 
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing an improved version of [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518777/941531), instead of using `PyUnicode_AsUTF8(...)` better to use [PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize).

Becasue string may contain null character (0 codepoint) somewhere in the middle, then your resulting `std::string` will contain truncated version of full string if you use `PyUnicode_AsUTF8(...)`.

```
Py_ssize_t size = 0;
char const * pc = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(obj, &size);
std::string s;
if (pc)
    s = std::string(pc, size);
else
    // Error, handle!
```