# Python 3: Python/C API String Problems

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-c-api

I am trying to use the Python/C API to run a Python function which returns a string. I want to store that returned string to a C++ variable, but I can't get it to work. I am using Python 3 and it seems like the `PyString_FromString()` method doesn't work anymore. Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue;

    Py_Initialize();

    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("ocr");

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "get_text");

    pValue = PyUnicode_FromString("ocr_noise.png");
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);

    std::string result = PyUnicode_FromObject(pValue);

    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pValue);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

The python file is called `ocr.py`, and the function I am trying to call is called `get_text(value)`. I am trying to pass in `"ocr_noise.png"` as an argument. Any ideas what I should do?

EDIT 2: I don't need to use std::string as in the code. What else can I use to store the string returned from the function?

Comment: What do you mean with "it seems like the `PyUnicode_FromString()` method doesn't work anymore"? Are you getting an exception? A segfault? Something else?

Comment: I meant PyString_FromString(). My bad.

Comment: There's no such thing as `PyString_FromString` in Python 3.

Comment: So how do I make this work in Python 3?

Comment: Have you considered using an existing wrapper library like Boost.Python instead of the low-level C API? It should make these things much simpler. That said, please read the guidelines here, your question is by definition off-topic, as explained there.

Comment: I think you want to use [`PyUnicode_AS_DATA`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AS_DATA), which returns a `std::wstring`

Comment: and there's also [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8) if you really want a `string`

Answer (score 3):

It's essential to check the return values of all Python functions. Python returns a `nullptr` if there was an error. So `PyUnicode_FromString()` works fine in your code. It just segfaults because `pValue` is a `nullptr` you got from `PyObject_CallObject()`. Putting `PyErr_Print()` just after this call prints:

```
TypeError: argument list must be a tuple
```

You need to pass a tuple of objects as argument, not a single `str`. Instead you might want to use `PyObject_CallFunction(pFunc, "O", pValue)` or `PyObject_CallFunction(pFunc, "s", "ocr_noise.png")`.

Additionally have a look into `PyImport_ImportModule()`. Furthermore

```
std::string result = PyUnicode_FromObject(pValue);
```

should not even compile since it returns a `PyObject *` not a `string`.

Comment: What should I do to store the returned string then?

Comment: [PyUnicode_FromObject()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_FromObject) might not be useful at all. `pValue` should be a unicode object already. See [Clean Way to Convert Python 3 Unicode to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515467/clean-way-to-convert-python-3-unicode-to-stdstring) for more detail on how to get a c string from the Python unicode object.